# How to display text in place of number in angularjs materials silder

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

[image]

What I want when you click on the slider, then on its tooltip it show text in place of the number.

Here is the code:

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" class="sliderdemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <md-content style="margin: 16px; padding:16px">
    <br>
    <br>
   <md-slider flex class="md-primary" md-discrete ng-model="rating3" step="1" min="1" max="5" aria-label="rating">
      </md-slider>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

Angular Code:

```
angular.module('MyApp')

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
});
```

Or you can refer the following link https://codepen.io/ankur-tiwari/pen/bVNEKJ

Comment: Can you please share the code ?

Comment: You can find it here. just created a simple slider and still searching for how to override the number with text http://codepen.io/ankur-tiwari/pen/bVNEKJ

Comment: @AnkurTiwari  I can't find any slider in your codepen. all I see is a date picker. can you have a look at it again. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after updating angular.js to Angular, Angular Material provided an option for **custom thumb label formatting** for the Angular slider.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Slider with custom thumb label formatting.
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'slider-formatting-example',
  templateUrl: 'slider-formatting-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['slider-formatting-example.css'],
})
export class SliderFormattingExample {
  formatLabel(value: number | null) {
    if (!value) {
      return 0;
    }

    if(value < 250)
    {
        return 'Low';
    }
    else if(value > 250 && value < 750)
    {
       return 'Medium';
    }
    else
    {
        return 'High';
    }

    return value;
  }
}
```

Html Code:

```
<mat-slider
  thumbLabel
  [displayWith]="formatLabel"
  tickInterval="1000"
  min="1"
  max="100000"></mat-slider>
```

> Note: I update my app from angular.js to Angular latest version.

Answer (score 4):

Angular Material does not support it.

for more detail check **slider.js** of angular-material module

```
function SliderDirective($$rAF, $window, $mdAria, $mdUtil, $mdConstant, $mdTheming, $mdGesture, $parse, $log) {
  return {
    scope: {},
    require: '?ngModel',
    template:
      '<div class="md-slider-wrapper">\
        <div class="md-track-container">\
          <div class="md-track"></div>\
          <div class="md-track md-track-fill"></div>\
          <div class="md-track-ticks"></div>\
        </div>\
        <div class="md-thumb-container">\
          <div class="md-thumb"></div>\
          <div class="md-focus-thumb"></div>\
          <div class="md-focus-ring"></div>\
          <div class="md-sign">\
            <span class="md-thumb-text"></span>\
          </div>\
          <div class="md-disabled-thumb"></div>\
        </div>\
      </div>',
    compile: compile
  };
```

inside this code

```
 <span class="md-thumb-text"></span>
```

is used to render the slider's range number.
and following method is used to render it

```
function postLink(scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl){
}
```

you can modify function's content like this

```
var _values = ["very low", "low", "average", "good", "best"];
thumbText.text( _values[ngModelCtrl.$viewValue] );
```

to render text rather integer value.

Comment: Is this doable without Angular? With jQuery for example?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that functionality is not supported as it's not technically part of the [material spec for sliders](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/sliders.html).

For a likert scale you should consider the [selection controls spec of material](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/selection-controls.html). Otherwise, you can get away with it in Angular Material by using a horizontal row of [radio buttons](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.radioButton).

Answer (score 1):

```
<p ng-bind="val" ng-init="val=20"></p>
            <div class="slider" ui-jq="slider"  ng-slider-model="val" ui-options="sliderOpt4"></div>
          </div>
```

Here is the an directive  you can access and show the value of controller value ..with html and css

```
.directive('ngSliderModel', ['$parse', function($parse) {
   return {
     scope: {
       ngSliderModel: '=',
       uiOptions: '='
     },
     restrict: 'A',
     required: ['ngSliderModel'],
     link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       // check there is uiOption or not 
       var options = ('uiOptions' in attrs) ? scope.uiOptions : {};
       // get the value of ngSlider Model 
       var val = scope.ngSliderModel;
       // if value is  range   [15,25]   then return values for uiOptions propertyName  else value for singles   
       var propName = (angular.isArray(val)) ? 'values' : 'value';
       /* if you  want to slide when the scope value changed not from slider... 
        watch the ngSliderModel attribute 
       */
       scope.$watch('ngSliderModel', function(newValue){

         element.slider(propName, newValue);
       });
       // set value for options 
       options[propName] = val;
       // binding slide event 
       element.bind('slide', function() {
         // Read the current value 
         var value = element.slider('option', propName);

         scope.$apply(function() {
           // Apply the value to scope 
           scope.ngSliderModel = value;
         });
       });
     }
   };
 }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Angualar-material dose not support this feature right now how ever you can do this thing by writing your own logic or you can create your own slider.

Answer (score 0):

Material2 team has picked up this issue and probably comeup with solution shortly.
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4776